# Не передаются данные через POST на HTTPS сервер

Tags: php, http, post, curl, https

Пытаюсь передать простейший массив вида:

```
$postFields = array(
  'SALT' => 'HGFFGHFGH',
  'AAA' => 'FOO',
  'BBB' => 'BAR'
);
```

сURL'ом через `POST`.

Делаю это так:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/script.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

В обработчике (`script.php` из ссылки `CURLOPT_URL`) у меня в итоге приходит пустой массив `$_POST` (вывожу из него `$_POST`).

Пара важных деталей:

1. И домен **с которого** я отправляю запрос и домен **на который** - работают через https.
2. Если я делаю запрос на тестовый сервер, который работает **без https** - всё работает нормально.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я натупил. :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответы, господа.

Проблема оказалась в следующем - на сервере, который предоставляет API, стоит редирект с `https://example.com/` на `https://internal.example.com/`. Когда делаю запросы ко второму - всё ок.

Буду разбираться в настройках сервера.

Answer (score 0):

В cURL необходимо поставить параметр CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/script.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: правильно, не увидел что вы через http_build_query отправляете )) поправил свой ответ

Comment: я пробовал по-разному. Это один из вариантов реализации. Без http_build_query тоже попробовал сейчас ещё раз - всё ещё не передаются данные. Причем, на тестовый домен, который без https - всё ок.